# Number Sequence Series – Question 1

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence, sequence

I want to share a question that is created by myself.

I will give a hint in 24 hours and my answer in 3 days given that nobody could answer my question.

Here is my number sequence:

$3/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1/3, 3/8, ?$

Comment: There is only 1 answer and the logic must be the simplest and neatest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> **1/6**

For this kind of question, we cannot just simply split the terms as every term is connected to each other.

Therefore, the logic is

> multiplication

Here is the process:

> (3/2)*(2/3)=1
>
> (2/3)*(3/4)=1/2
>
> (3/4)*(1/3)=1/4
>
> (1/3)*(3/8)=1/8
>
> (3/8)*(***1/6***)=1/16

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: (It is generally nicer to give a solver some hints and some time to let them come up with the intended full solution themselves; if their answer is substantially close, you might instead annotate their final solution with, e.g., "Added by OP" notes that fill in missing or incorrect details.  Having said that, in *this* case it's rather hard to argue how the answer offered by @Stojan Samojlovski is in any way lacking; it has the intended answer via a well justified mechanism that is ultimately equivalent to the method your own answer describes.)

Comment: Okay, I get it! Next time I will give a hint first. I am still new here sorry...

Comment: (1) You even ***said*** that you would wait three days before posting your answer.  (2) Stojan Samojlovski [got the right answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84021/19765#84042), with logic that’s mathematically equivalent to yours, and your explanation isn’t really much simpler or neater.  You should have just accepted their answer.   (For that matter, [Ak19](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84021/19765#84022) pretty much got it right, also, but their explanation is very unclear.)

Answer (score 7):

Obviously the answer is

> $1/6$

because

> The even and odd terms are multiplied by $ 1/2 $.

That is,

> For odd: 
>  $3/2 \times 1/2 = 3/4.$ 
>  $3/4 \times 1/2 = 3/8.$
>
> For even: 
>  $2/3 \times 1/2 = 2/6\implies 1/3.$ 
>  $1/3 \times 1/2 = 1/6.$

Comment: You might as well say [(ROT13) Nsgre gur svefg gjb grezf, rnpu vf bar unys gur frpbaq cerivbhf grez](http://www.decode.org/?q=Nsgre+gur+svefg+gjb+grezf%2C+rnpu+vf+bar+unys+gur+frpbaq+cerivbhf+grez.); i.e., [(hover over this)](/. "A(n) = 1/2 * A(n-2)").

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> $\frac{2}{3}$ or $\frac{1}{6}$

Reason

> For answer 1:
> Each even term is the reciprocal of the preceding odd term. If the fraction is still reducible, then the remainder is the even term.
> $2/3$ is irreducible, so it is the second term. $4/3 = 1 + 1/3$. Thus, $1/3$ is the fourth term.
> Similarly, $8/3 = 2 + 2/3$. So, the sixth term should be $2/3$ $$$$
> For answer 2:
> $A_n = \frac{1}{2}A_{n-2}$ [a simpler version posted by @Peregrine Rook. Thanks]
>
> So we have
> \begin{array}lA_1 = 3/2\\A_2 = 2/3\\A_3 = \frac12A_1 = \frac12\times 3/2=3/4\\A_4 = \frac12A_2 = \frac12\times 2/3=1/3\\A_5 = \frac12A_3 = \frac12\times 3/4=3/8\\A_6 = \frac12A_4 = \frac12\times 1/3=1/6 \text{(the answer)}\phantom{WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW}\\ ~~\vdots\end{array}

Comment: One of your answers is correct! But the logic is wrong sorry.

Comment: @PeregrineRook Thanks for your comment. But at that time I didn't get this one.

Comment: I believe that it’s clearer now.   If you don’t like it, you are of course free to roll it back.

Comment: By the way, when you have multiple *different* answers to a question, it’s (at least occasionally) OK if you post a couple of separate answers. (Click on the “Add Another Answer” button.  It will ask whether you’re sure; click “OK”.) It allows people to vote for the answer that they think is better, and it lets you delete the wrong one without a trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is 0/3
Alternating we get:
3/2,3/4,3/8,...(pattern is (3/2)^(n+1))
2/3,1/3,?,...(pattern is 2/3-(n*1/3))
Following the pattern we get:
?=0/3
Next is:
3/16