# Number Sequence Series-Question 4

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

I want to share a series of questions that are created by myself.

I will give a hint in 24 hours and my answer in 3 days if nobody could answer my question.

Previous ones are here:

[Number Sequence Series-Question 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84021/number-sequence-series-question-1)

[Number Sequence Series-Question 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84048/number-sequence-series-question-2)

[Number Sequence Series-Question 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84070/number-sequence-series-question-3)

Here is the new number sequence:

**21870,1215,?,15**

If you guys want some extremely challenging questions. Please check these two questions posted by me.

[Number sequences: 000, X00... and 6X000X9, 700XX08](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84014/number-sequences-000-x00-and-6x000x9-700xx08)

[What are the alphabets in the question mark?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83925/what-are-the-alphabets-in-the-question-mark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 135.

You can generate this by

> dividing by the sum of the digits to get the next number. For instance the sum of digits of 21870 is 2+1+8+7+0=18, so divide by 18 to get 1215, whose digit sum is 1+2+1+5=9, so we divide by 9 to get 135, and divide by 9 again to get 15 as desired.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Congrats.

Comment: As I said, the logic of a good number sequence question must be the neatest and it comes from the question ITSELF.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> $135$. Remove all factors of $2$ and divide by $9$.

Comment: Sorry, it is not correct. Pls check the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is,

> 270.

Reason

> The ratio of first and second number of a pair yields 18. 
> $$$$
>  Also, we can find that the ratio of second and fourth number is 81, so the ratio of first and third numbers should also be 81.
> $$$$
>  $\frac{21870}{1215} = 18$ So, third term = $15\cdot 18 = 270$
> $$$$
> Also, $\frac{1215}{15} = 81$ so, third term = $\frac{21870}{81} = 270$

Comment: Sorry, it is not correct. Pls check the right answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, and when are you posting your next question?

Comment: You can try my Number Sequence 3 and I will post my fifth question in 3 hours.